# Binary Serialization of C# for GameObject in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity, serialization

I'm trying to serialize a **GameObject** (with children and textures) using the binary serialization for C#.

It works with many data types but not with **GameObject**. In the docs it says should be serializable (http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html):

> Serializable types are:
>    - All classes inheriting from UnityEngine.Object, for example GameObject ....

I've read suggestions of using the asset of UnitySerialization, but that is overkill for me, I just need to store a **GameObject** on my scene (that will be generated by many users) and load them all in another scene.

This is the code (I'm following this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J6FfcJpbPXE&feature=player_embedded)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary; 
using System.IO;

public class GameControl : MonoBehaviour {

    public static GameControl control;

    public GameObject drawing;
    public string drawName;

    void Awake () {
        if (control == null)
        {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
            control = this;
        }
        else if (control != this)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public void Save ()
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/drawing.drawli");

        UserDraw data = new UserDraw();
        data.drawing = drawing;

        bf.Serialize(file, data);
        file.Close();
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/drawing.draw"))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/drawing.draw", FileMode.Open);
            UserDraw data = (UserDraw)bf.Deserialize(file);
            file.Close();

            drawing = data.drawing;
        }
    }

}

[System.Serializable]
class UserDraw
{
    public GameObject drawing;
}
```

Check the Save/Load functions. I'm just trying to store the "drawing" (GamObject), save it and load it. That's all! Is very simple. With other data types it works. But not with **GameObject**.

This is the (execution) error:

*SerializationException: Type UnityEngine.GameObject is not marked as Serializable.*

Comment: You might want to check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2P_9s3KhdU) where Tom shows how he converts everything into a byte array and then serializes all of it.

Answer (score 3):

> SerializationException: Type UnityEngine.GameObject is not marked as
>   Serializable.

That means `UnityEngine.GameObject` is not marked with the [`Serializable` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx), which is a requirement (just because Unity says a type is serializable doesn't mean it's serializable with *all* serialization engines; in this case, it probably means that the type is serializable with Unity's engine, not the one that is part of the .NET BCL).

You can either use Unity's serialization mechanism, or you can try your hand at implementing an [`ISerializableSurrogate` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializationsurrogate(v=vs.110).aspx) for the Unity game object (this is likely to be tricky, and more effort than just using Unity's serialization).